# How to pass a CSRF token safely to a separate VueJS frontend?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, csrf

Laravel(backend) and VueJS(frontend created with Vue CLI) are separated, hence have different domains and repositories. I am wondering what is the best way to pass a CSRF token from Laravel to VueJS **safely**.

I've found some old questions here and on Laracasts but they are either irrelevant, outdated or have no answer. Here are a few:

[Pass csrf token from Laravel to Vue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50325287/pass-csrf-token-from-laravel-to-vue)

[Creating a sign up token for Laravel app from separate frontend app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33189948/creating-a-sign-up-token-for-laravel-app-from-separate-frontend-app)

[(Laracasts forum) CSRF in separate angular app](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/csrf-in-separate-angular-app)

I am aware that Laravel ships with `$except` array in VerifyCSRFToken middleware. Adding frontend's URL to this list will create a security flaw, am I correct?

Comment: checkout this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42242513/laravel-enable-verifycsrftoken-for-specific-routes

Comment: You need to add <meta> of CSRF in the index page and add the CSRF in each ajax call !

Comment: @Maraboc I've mentioned that Laravel does not generate any view in this case, so I can't parse meta tag. I have a completely separate, standalone Vue instance.

Comment: @Maraboc that is how laravel does it if you don't separate frontend from backend. When separated, it makes no sense to store it in HTML. Andrii: for SPAs, you shouldnt use sessions for authentication but rather JWT authentication, e.g. with Laravel Passport. If you don't use sessions anymore, your CSRF token becomes obsolete.

Comment: @MatthiasS makes sense, now I get it. I think this should be an answer to my question. Feel free to post it.

Comment: What is the answer for this question just to help other poeple find it ?

Comment: Your last comment answers my question. Now I am using Laravel Passport instead of playing with CSRF token.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of using a standalone application (vue, react, angular ....) the best solution is to use [Laravel Passport](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/passport) instead of using CSRF tokens.